# SilverStripe template statement returns false positive

Tags: php, silverstripe

I've been at this for hours. I've got two pages types:
`Page extends SiteTree` which holds no additional `$db` fields **and** I have a 
`SubPage extends Page` which holds `$db` entry `Banner`.

This is the if statement in the **Page.ss** template:

```
<% if $Banner %>
    <% include Banner %> <- include the banner .ss template
<% end_if %>
```

For some reason this returns **true** even if there is no `$db` field named *Banner* in the current PageType. However, there is a Table in the database named **Banner** as well, and it seems that the existence of this table triggers $Banner.

Is there a way to fix this by making the template clear that $Banner refers to a $db field, and if this $db field is not declared for this pagetype, then return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to be 100% sure is to create a function in the controller of the SubPage called like `BannerExists` and then use that in the `if`.

```
public function BannerExists() {
    return !empty($this->Banner);
}
```

This is because Silverstripe is returning an empty string where the field isn't found.

Alternatively you might use...

```
<% if not $Banner == "" %>
   <% include Banner %>
<% end_if %>
```

or...

```
<% if $Banner == "" %><% else %>
   <% include Banner %>
<% end_if %>
```

Comment: This is very strange, I've tried this code before but it didn't work. I probably overlooked something. Thanks for saving the day Barry.

Comment: Happy to @Faloude, keep the Silverstripe questions coming :)